# How to push different view controller from collection view didSelectItemAt based on Json id in swift

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

My project contains collectionView.. but how to push different viewcontroller from didSelectItemAt based on json id.. and i have separate vewcontrollers for each id.. but i am unable to push different viewcontrolls with didSelectItemAt based on json id.

here is my Json for collectionView:

```
{
"financer": [
    {
        "id": "45",
        "icon": "https://hello.com//images/img1.png"
    }
    {
        "id": "40",
        "icon": "https://hello.com//images/img2.png"
     }
     .
     .
     .
   ]
 }
```

here is my home collectionview code:

```
import UIKit

struct JsonData {

var iconHome: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
}
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
var idArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeServiceCall()
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName

    if let url = NSURL(string: aData.iconHome ?? "") {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            cell.paymentImage.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as! MakePaymentViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    let indexPathHome = indexPath.row
    print("home collectionItem indexpath \(indexPathHome)")

}

//MARK:- Service-call

func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices/getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }

        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for financer in financerArray {

                let id = financer["id"] as! String
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String
                print("home financer id \(id)")
                self.idArray.append(id)
                print("the home financer idsArray \(self.idArray.append(id))")
                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? ""))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }

    }).resume()
}
}
```

when I click on any item from collectionview i am able to push same view controller but i need to push different view controller based on json id. i dont know how to and where to use json id to push differnt viewcontroller using didselectItem atIndexPath. anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `homeServiceCall` function

```
func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices/getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }

        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for financer in financerArray {

                let id = financer["id"] as! String
                let pic = financer["icon"] as? String

                self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? ""))
                self.idArray.append(id)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }

    }).resume()
}
```

Create a string property called `financerId` in your `MakePaymentViewController`

In your `didSelect` function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MakePaymentViewController") as? MakePaymentViewController {
        nextViewController.finacerId = idArray[indexPath.row]
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**Update**

```
for financer in financerArray {
      if let id = financer["id"] as? Int {
          self.idArray.append(id)
      }

      if let pic = financer["icon"] as? String {
          elf.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic))
      }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting ids in idArray... the home financer idsArray () in console... if i print seperate id... home financer id 45

Comment: That's why i suggest you modify the homeServiceCall function, add that line 
`self.idArray.append(id)`
You will have an array stores all ids

Comment: yes i did it in home service call.. i have updated my post

Comment: May be you didnt get ids when parsing json response

Comment: home financerData [["tpe": L S PUBLIC SCHOOL, "is_public": 1, "block": 0, "id": 45, "category": 8, "icon": https://dev.com/images/LSPUBLICSCHOOL_icon.png, "payment_mode": <__NSArrayI 0x600003a98c60>(
    {
    id = 13;
    "is_public" = 0;
    "paymentmode_code" = AADHAR;
    "paymentmode_icon" = "https://dev.com/images/Aadharhdpi.png";
    status = 1;
    },
    {
    
    id = 12;
    "is_public" = 0;
    "paymentmode_code" = AW;
    "paymentmode_icon" = "https://dev/images/0Wallet.png";
    status = 1;
    },

Comment: Please check my update answer. I see that the id field is int, not string so the problem is in your parsing approach @iosSwift

Comment: @iosSwift sure, i believe that the problem is in the way you parse json, btw please notice about force cast (!), try to avoid it as much as possible, use `if let` & `guard let` instead

Comment: your solution is correct but i am unable to add ids into array but single id iam getting if i give it to string.. if u got time can u suggest me why its happends like this.. and thank you for ur suggestion with solution about (!).. i follow if let and guard let

Comment: If your backend return the `id` in string then let's change this line `if let id = financer["id"] as? Int {}` to `if let id = financer["id"] as? String {}` @iosSwift